# How to configure info.plist file for flutter social login "google and facebook"?

Tags: ios, flutter, google-signin, facebook-login, info.plist

I am trying to implement Flutter google sign in and facebook login using flutter package   google_sign_in: ^5.4.2 and flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.1 I configured both for android as well as iOS properly. The problem is google login and facebook login is not working at a time for iOS. I meant sometimes google sign in is working and another time facebook login is working but google login is not. I guess there are something wrong in info.plist file code configuration or alignment.

[image]

If I set google info.plist configuration code before facebook then google is not working and if I set facebook code before google then facebook is not working.

Here you go with my info.plist code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>*****</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>*******</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>********</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>



    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>sms</string>
        <string>tel</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>


    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To take user profile image</string>
    <key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow access to the documents folder to select files.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow access to your location for better user experience</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Use to capture audio for image picker plugin</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>To choose user profile image</string>
    <key>UIActivityTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIActivityTypePostToFacebook</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypePostToTwitter</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypePostToWeibo</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeMessage</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeMail</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypePrint</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeAssignToContact</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypePostToFlickr</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypePostToVimeo</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeAirDrop</string>
        <string>UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>


     <!-- Put me in the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file -->
            <!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
            <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                    <string>Editor</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
                        <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
                        <string>*********</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->


    <!-- facebook log-in Section -->

        <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
          <dict>
          <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
          <array>
            <string>fb*******</string>
          </array>
          </dict>
        </array>
        <key>FacebookAppID</key>
        <string>*******</string>
        <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
        <string>********</string>
        <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
        <string>********</string>


</dict>
</plist>
```

Could anyone please help me regard this issue? Thanks in advance.